# update UpdatePanel based on changes to Gridview

Tags: ajax, gridview, updatepanel

I am trying to conditionally update my updatepanel based on changes that have been made to my gridview. I am having trouble. This is inside the BugsGridView_RowUpdated function.

```
if ( /*Changes have been made to gridview */)
{
ActivityUpdatePanel.Update();
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try assigning your `GridView` as a trigger of your `UpdatePanel` in you aspx?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="ActivityUpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="BugsGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">       
            <Columns>        
                ...
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="BugsGridView" EventName="RowUpdated" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I am not sure about the event name RowUpdated though.

Edit: maybe the correct event is [RowUpdating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating.aspx)